# Agrupando SUMS por data no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Estou tentando fazer um pegar os totais dos pedidos  agrupados por data da seguinte forma

```
SELECT 
       sum(pit.preco) AS preco,
       sum(pit.quantidade) AS quantidade
FROM cliente c
LEFT JOIN erp_pedido ped ON ped.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN erp_pedido_it pit ON pit.id_pedido = ped.id_pedido

WHERE ped.tipo = 'C'    
  AND ped.id_cliente = 2

GROUP BY 
         ped.data_inicio ,
         c.nome,
         ped.id_cliente

ORDER BY ped.data_inicio desc,
         ped.id_cliente
```

Isso resulta em

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  1.5000   ;  209.0000
2017-02-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  3.0000   ;  418.0000
2017-01-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  4.5000   ;  627.0000
2016-12-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  6.0000   ;  836.0000
2016-11-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  7.5000   ;  1045.0000
2016-10-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  9.0000   ;  1254.0000
2016-09-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  10.5000  ;  1463.0000
2016-08-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  12.0000  ;  1672.0000
2016-07-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  13.5000  ;  1881.0000
2016-06-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  15.0000  ;  2090.0000
2016-05-01 00:00:00  ;  CLIENT NAME  ;  2  ;  16.5000  ;  2299.0000
```

Eu esperava que ele somasse separadamente para cada data e nao somasse tudo sequencialmente, deveria ficar assim:

```
PRECO   ; QUANTIDADE
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
1.5000  ; 209.0000
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O resultado que você postou não foi gerado por esse select foi?

Comment: Deixe assim: GROUP BY  ped.data_inicio

Comment: Tem algo errado em seu post , o "Isso resulta em" parace trocado com o "deveria ficar assim' , mas a solução do @Reginaldo Rigo parace ser a certa

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo é o mesmo sql eu só retirei as colunas que nao sao relevantes do  select que eu postei, eu nao consigo deixar só o ped.data_inicio o Postgre exige os outros campos no group by

Comment: Por isso que é importante o mesmo SQL, porque senão nós ficamos falando do que SELECT que estamos vendo e você falando do outro SELECT que você esta vendo. Mas enfim, se você colocar os campos C.nome,  ped.id_cliente no SELECT então o banco vai exigir mesmo que se agrupe por esse campos também e aí você não conseguirá o resultado que espera. Você precisa retirar esses campos do SELECT para poder agrupar apenas pela DATA_INICIO.